# unique legend on multiple charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts to generate 8 #containers, or charts. Now I want to link one legend to all containers, which is sort of tricky.

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (event) {        
                            var XYZ = $('#container2').highcharts(),
                            series = XYZ.get(this.options.id); //get corresponding series

                        if (series) {
                            if (this.visible) {
                                series.hide();
                            } else {
                                series.show();

                                }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Gives me a link between two containers.

Tried adding

```
for(var num=0; num<containerNums; num++)
                        {
                            if(num != exclude)
                            {
                              var XYZ = $('#container'+num).highcharts(),
```

to make it go through all possible containers (container#1-#8), but no results.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the related example: http://jsfiddle.net/u7FQS/15/ which is based on pie chart, but mechanism will be similiar.

```
$(chart.series[0].data).each(function(i, e) {
        e.legendItem.on('click', function(event) {
            var legendItem=e.name;

            event.stopPropagation();

            $(chart.series).each(function(j,f){
                   $(this.data).each(function(k,z){
                       if(z.name==legendItem)
                       {
                           if(z.visible)
                           {
                               z.setVisible(false);
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               z.setVisible(true);
                           }
                       }
                   });
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Hmm... Can you get this to work with multiple column charts? Pie charts are sort of special in Highcharts (don't need to be rendered into multiple containers) and I've tried incorporating this solution to my problem without success :/

Comment: See the example http://jsfiddle.net/u7FQS/135/, obviously it is not optimal, and you can use loops etc.